# Python list comprehensions for dictionaries

Tags: python, lambda, nltk

I'm coming from Java/C and I'm trying to work with line comprehensions. I've got the following code but can't seem to get the line comprehension equivalent to work.

```
stop_words = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english'))

tokenizer = nltk.tokenize.RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(text)

token_map = {}

for token in tokens:
    token = token.lower()
    if english_dict.check(token):
        if token not in stop_words:
            if token in token_map:
                token_map[token] += 1
            else:
                token_map[token] = 1

sorted_map = sorted(token_map.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))

return sorted_map
```

Comment: If you just want to solve the problem, take a look at `Counter` class from module *collections*, which also provides a nice `most_common()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
tokens = tuple(map(str.lower,tokens))
token_map = {token: tokens.count(token)
             for token in set(tokens)
             if english_dict.check(token) and token not in stop_words}
sorted_map = sorted(token_map.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

**Edit:**

My answer was on what you want but if you want faster and better solution see @AlexHall answer.

Comment: If there are M tokens and N unique tokens, this will take O(MN) time, which is slow.

Comment: @AlexHall What is your opinion? How would it be optimized?

Comment: And why down vote? He asked for comprehension solution and I wrote this.

Comment: It would be optimised by not using `.count`. I gave my answer for an alternative. I explained why I downvoted, it's because it's slow. OP's code is probably faster (certainly for many tokens) so that should be the minimum benchmark.

Comment: @AlexHall Although you gave me down vote but I know that your code is better than mine and voted up. I just did what he wants :)
Also learned new things. Tnx

Answer (score 1):

You can replace everything from `token_map = {}` and after with:

```
return Counter(token for token in map(str.lower, tokens)
               if english_dict.check(token)
               if token not in stop_words
               ).most_common()
```

Add this import to the top of the file:

```
from collections import Counter
```